# How to reload asp.net core identity options at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

We've implemented an administration system to allow the admin to change password complexity rules. At startup, these options are applied to asp.net core identity in `services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(setupAction)`.
So these options are applied whenever we restart the server application.
How can we force reload these settings at runtime (without application restart)

Answer (score 3):

Do not set the options in Startup. Instead add a custom password validator:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddPasswordValidator<UsernameAsPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>>();
```

From: https://andrewlock.net/creating-custom-password-validators-for-asp-net-core-identity-2/

Comment: I kinda hoped to find a way to avoid this. But thanks for the hint, we might have to fallback on this.

Answer (score 0):

delete password options from services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(setupAction)

then add password options with   `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>{ options.Password.RequireDigit = 3;....});`

sample change identity option from database

```
  private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IdentityOptions options;
    private readonly DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions _tokenProviderOptions;
    private readonly EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions _emailTokenProrvider;

    public UpdateHandler(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, IOptions<IdentityOptions> options, 
        IOptions<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions> tokenProviderOptions,
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> emailTokenProrvider)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _emailTokenProrvider = emailTokenProrvider.Value;
        _tokenProviderOptions = tokenProviderOptions.Value;
        this.options = options.Value;
    }


    public async Task<ResultResponse> Handle(UpdatePolicy request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        if (_unitOfWork.IdentitySettingPolicy.SettingExist(request.IdentitySetting.Id))
        {
            var setting = request.IdentitySetting;
            _unitOfWork.IdentitySettingPolicy.UpdateSetting(request.IdentitySetting);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            options.Password.RequireDigit = setting.RequireDigit;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = setting.RequiredLength;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = setting.RequireNonAlphanumeric;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = setting.RequireUppercase;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = setting.RequireLowercase;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = setting.RequiredUniqueChars;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(setting.DefaultLockoutTimeSpanMinute);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = setting.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

            // SignIn settings
            //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            // options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = setting.RequireConfirmedAccount;

            //Email token provider
            options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "EmailConFirmation";
            _tokenProviderOptions.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(setting.TokenLifespanHour);
            _emailTokenProrvider.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(setting.TokenLifespanHour);
            return new ResultResponse(true, "Policy Updated", request.IdentitySetting);

        }

        throw new Exception(ErrorRes.EntityNotExist);



    }
}
```